# Meaning of the expression "A far l'amore comincia tu"

Tags: translation

The Raffaella Carrà's song [A far l'amore comincia tu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7_MRQTCOjo) is quite famous in Europe and was popularized by the Bob Sinclar's remix, part of the soundtrack of the beautiful Paolo Sorrentino's movie "La Grande Bellezza". You can find the lyrics [here](http://genius.com/Raffaella-carr-a-far-lamore-comincia-tu-liebelei-lyrics).

My mother tongue being French, a first naive approach to the expression "a far l'amore comincia tu" would be "you begin to make love", but I do not think it fits with the spirit of the movie scene. I haven't been able to find a reliable translation and it is why I am asking here what it does really mean.

My guess would be it means something like "You eventually allow yourself to love" in the context, but I would like that to be confirmed/invalidated.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @MoebiusCorzer!

Comment: "You begin to make love" it is a quite good translation. The song was written for Raffaella Carra in order to confirm her as a sexy icon in Italian people's immagination. The song tells the story of a woman who asks her man to make love.

Comment: Ok, so it is not an expression. Grazie!

Comment: I found also this translation: "you’re the one who takes the initiative to make love", from the website www.lyrictranslate.com, which is a literal meaning of this phrase.

Comment: Yes, I have just seen it but was not sure of the reliability of this source. So "You begin to make love" would be a better translation than the literal one you quoted?

Comment: In my opinion "You begin to make love" is better than the literal translation.

Comment: @Arcsn I would consider that translation wrong. The verb is in the imperative mood ("comincia", not "cominci"), so a better translation would be "Be the one who takes [...]"

Comment: @fqq Your translation seems to be more coherent with the rest of the song. Any of you is a native Italian speaker?

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer I am

Comment: @fqq I strongly disagree. In English language the imperative sentence gives a command. It usually ends with a period, but it may also end with an exclamation point (!). e.g. "Please pass the salt." is a command. So "you begin/start to make love" is also a command.

Comment: @Arcsn I was referring to "you’re the one who takes the initiative to make love", which IMO is wrong because it's clearly not a command.

Comment: @fqq, oh I got it now. :-)

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer I'd say that the most idiomatic translation is *Take the lead on making love*

Comment: **Historical note**: the term *fare l'amore* doesn't necessarily mean to have sexual intercourse, especially when mentioned in text from say 1950 or earlier. In those cases it simply means to flirt/talk/kiss/go on a date etc. In fact if you search for traditional songs between the end of '800 and beginning of '900 you'll find *tons* of references to *fare all'amore* in situations which *today* would look really weird if not obscene if you interpret is as just "having sexual intercourse".

Comment: @Bakuriu All you say is true, however if you listen to the song it does not leave much room to interpretation :)

Comment: In French it would, probably, sound something like: «C'est à toi de commencer à faire l'amour», la phrase adressée à une femme.

Comment: @JoePyat: This should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: @JoePyat: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/2521)

Answer (score 5):

I'm Italian, the exact meaning of the expression is imperative:

> be the first to make love

It is an inusual structure, common in spoken Italian: it is an invitation to her partner to make the first move.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible that it is more an invitation to the (female) listener than her partner? I mean, later she sings about "lui" where I think it refers to the potential partner of the listener.

Comment: "sii il primo a fare l'amore"? hmmm not sure... maybe it should be something like: "you do the first move (in order to make love)"? for me it makes more sense.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer in Italian it can be used to address both sexes, because "tu" means "you" (m or f).

Comment: Yes, as it is in French. I mentioned "female" because with the clarification of the title, the song seems to be feminist, in some sense, enjoining the listener to lead the act of making love. Doesn't "Fagli vedere che non è un gioco" mean "Make him see it is not a game"?

Comment: Yes. The song was written in order to encourage a male to make love. The title, by itself, can be used for both male or female.

Comment: I am not exactly knowledgeable about Ms Carrà's songs, but the (con)text suggests that it is a woman addressing another woman to take initiative in the bedroom. The two of them talk *about* a man: *Se **lui** ti porta su un letto vuoto / ... / Fa**gli** vedere che non è un gioco*. (Not quite Bechdel test material, but...)

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: As DaG mentions its a suggestion given to whatever woman is listening to the song to be the one to take the initiative... I must be old... And the translation could be  even "*making love, you start*" after all a reversed order wasn't that rare in the old English (think Shakespeare's "Round about the cauldron go"), I believe its German influence, they still use the form AFAIK.  Then again the sentence in itself can be translated in different ways so pick the one you like best.

Comment: Yes, of course it is referred to a woman, my mistake. @Arcsn I gave the most litteral translation I could, but as I specified the best interpretation is "make the first move".